# How can I automate window tiling with a custom width? (Cinnamon)

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, window-management, xdotool, wmctrl

I am running Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon 2.4.8.

I really like xdotool, but it conflicts with Cinnamon's awesome snapping/tiling feature.

If I run the following command, it does **NOT** work if the current window is snapped to a corner/side/fullscreen.

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowsize 500 1080 windowmove 1420 0
```

I would like to keep it snapped, but with a custom width. If it is **NOT** snapped, it works.

**Main goal: Snap a window to the right side, with 500 width (via a command)**

However, it's probably impossible with xdotool.

I would prefer not to install anything else, and do it all with cinnamon, but if anyone thinks I can achieve my goal with wmctrl, then I'll give it a shot.

### Desired output vs. current output

http://s115.photobucket.com/user/ericrazy2000/media/snapped.png.html

http://s115.photobucket.com/user/ericrazy2000/media/NOTsnapped.png.html

Answer (score 3):

Does this command work for you (uses `wmctrl`):

```
dist500fromright=$((`xrandr | grep \* | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/x.*$//'`-500));y=`xrandr | grep \* | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/^.*x//'`;wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,$dist500fromright,0,500,$y
```

---

### Breakdown

`xrandr` outputs a list of geometries and the `*` shows the current mode.  For example:

```
$ xrandr | grep \*
   1920x1200      60.0*+
```

We use `awk` to capture the first column of output, and `sed` to grab the dimensions delimited by the `x` character.

```
$ xrandr | grep \* | awk '{print $1}' 
1920x1200

$ xrandr | grep \* | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/x.*$//'
1920
```

Bash allows us to do math on command output by wrapping it in `$((...))`:

```
$ echo 5+2
5+2

$ echo $((5+2))
7
```

So above, we wrap the command in `$((...))` and subtract 500 to get the x-coordinate position 500 pixels from the right edge of the screen:

```
$ echo  $((`xrandr | grep \* | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/x.*$//'`-500))
1420
```

Note, in order to subtract 500 from 1920, we had to put the command that produces 1920 in backticks first.

We set the output above to the variable `dist500fromright`, and do something similar to store the y-dimensions of the screen in the `y` variable:

```
$ dist500fromright=$((`xrandr | grep \* | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/x.*$//'`-500))

$ y=`xrandr | grep \* | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/^.*x//'`;
```

We are now ready to run the wmctrl command

```
$ wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert

$ wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,$dist500fromright,0,500,$y
```

where the latter command resizes and moves the active window while the former allows the resize/move on snapped windows.

Comment: Your command works pretty much exactly as my xdotool example above.

It also deals with the same problems with the xdotool method:
1. It does not move the window if it is tiled/snapped.
2. It does not leave the window tiled/snapped in the end

Comment: @TuxForLife, I updated it for Cinnamon snapping.  Please let me know if it works.

Comment: You are very close! However, I would like the final window to be snapped to the right. It is almost, there, it just needs to be snapped to the edge of my screen

Comment: @TuxForLife, Does this command not align the window to the right edge of the screen?  Could you describe (or post a screenshot) of what it is doing?  [Here](http://i.imgur.com/5vs28eP.jpg) is what I get.

Comment: The snapped one, I snapped it manually, then I adjusted the size by dragging the edge of the window.  http://s115.photobucket.com/user/ericrazy2000/media/snapped.png.html

    http://s115.photobucket.com/user/ericrazy2000/media/NOTsnapped.png.html

Comment: So by "snapped" you mean a curved border, or is there something else?

Comment: When it is snapped, there should not be a curved border. I put 2 links if it was hard to tell. There you can compare between snapped and not snapped

Comment: @TuxForLife, I don't know how to restyle the border without corners.  Good luck!

Comment: It's not just restyling the border without corners. Doing it with our current methods leaves a slight gap still from the window to the edge of the screen. I think it is beyond the control of xdotool and wmctrl, and should be done with Cinnamon. Thanks for the help regardless!

Comment: @TuxForLife, I wish I could see your exact setup (mine doesn't have that gap), but you could always try changing `-500))` to `-500+2))` or `-500+4))` or whatever until it looks right for you.

Comment: Using your method, it positions it really well, but the only problem is that it isn't officially "snapped"

Is there any way I can do a command with Cinnamon?

Comment: I recommend getting the geometries with xdotool instead. Your method assumes I have only 1 monitor. `width=$(xdotool getdisplaygeometry | cut -d' ' -f1) ; height=$(xdotool getdisplaygeometry | cut -d' ' -f2)`

Comment: I am running out of time for the bounty. I would rather give the bounty points to someone rather than waste them. Unless someone provides the answer I anticipated for, I can give the bounty points to whoever gives me the best answer to the following question first. How can I unsnap/unfullscreen a window using just xdotool?

Comment: `xdotool key F11` [#hit full screen](http://www.ananddrs.com/2014/03/07/firefox-fullscreen/)

Comment: @TuxForLife, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hello, that just puts Firefox in "Full screen" mode. It doesn't affect the window size. I would like it to be any window, not just Firefox

Answer (score 3):

You might need to remove some maximization flags first:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz;\
xdotool getactivewindow windowsize 500 1080 windowmove 1420 0;\
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert
```

Comment: This did indeed help a bit. If the window is tiled at the top or bottom, the command works and resizes/relocates the window. However, if the window is tiled to the left or right, the command does not relocate/resize. Also, I would really like to have the final state of the window to be tiled to the edge of the screen

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: Hmmm. While it is working very nicely, it does not put it in snapped mode. I can tell it is not in snapped mode since a shadow is visible, and the top corners are rounded. If the window is snapped, then this does not occur

Comment: I am running out of time for the bounty. I would rather give the bounty points to someone rather than waste them. Unless someone provides the answer I anticipated for, I can give the bounty points to whoever gives me the best answer to the following question first. How can I unsnap/unfullscreen a window using just xdotool?

Comment: You probably won't be able to tile the window using either wmctrl or xdotool. The reason is, `muffin` (the cinamon window manager) uses a nonstandard state for that (_NET_WM_STATE_TILED) as you can learn from `xprop` output. I  don't think you can get at that reasonably efficiently from a currently existing higher level tool. You'd need to hack at muffin's C code.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of a very funky solution dragging the mouse with xdotool. It actually works much better than I expected. If you can provide me with a way to "remove some maximization flags" with xdotool by itself, I will reward you the bounty points

Answer (score 0):

You can use wmctrl for this,

as example from the old linux mint mate forum, I think you also can use it in cinnamon:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,width,height
```

This should work.

If your screen is fullscreen you should use:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_horz,maximized_vert
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,width,height
```

source:

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=109020

or use ctrl + numpad to get the desired location

source:

http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/tbqky/window_snapping_pseudotiling_wm/

Comment: Please take a look at the previous discussions I had with the other answers. I am aware I can manually snap it, but I am trying to do it with a command.