# How to customize window tiling zones/grid?

Tags: cinnamon, window-management, wmctrl

In Cinnamon, pressing <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>arrow keys</kbd> (or other similar shortcut) resizes current window into a tile (snaps to grid). How can I customize this grid?

For example I would like to split screen into 3 equal vertical zones so that the window would behave like this:

[image]

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435659/customize-kde-tiling-grid) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203715/how-can-i-automate-window-tiling-with-a-custom-width-cinnamon) questions shows how to define shortcuts for putting windows in an *aboslute* position on the screen. It's nice, but I would prefer to use arrowkey-based shortcuts to *move the window around*.

I'm using Cinnamon (from Linux Mint), but a generic answer would be most welcome.

Comment: I'd like to modify the grid to allow tiling of two windows in a quarter of the screen. Very interested in knowing if this can be done.

Comment: This isn't a helpful comment I"m afraid, but I"ve been researching this for some time and I'm pretty sure as of min 18.1 there is no way to do it in cinnamon. You need some other wm tool, I think the best is i3 but it seems like a you give up everything, or a lot in order to have decent windows management.  Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Check the answers on [this possible duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139730/209677)

Comment: If you dare to switch from Cinnamon to Budgie (which is pretty similar), check out [Window Shuffler](https://frontpagelinux.com/tutorials/window-shuffler-tiling-window-management-from-ubuntu-budgie/). -- I personally could not switch yet as NixOS does not provide a package for Window Shuffler (yet).

Answer (score 6):

Cinnamon provided an extension called `gtile` for enhanced tiling, which might be what you are looking for.

To install the `gtile` extension: open the Menu -> Settings -> Extensions.

Comment: After installing, make sure you enable the extension "return to 'Manage' tab, select the extension, click the + button at the bottom.

Comment: Also, this is not working very well for me on Mint 19. I activate it with SUPER+G, double click a tile, and it shoves my window way up to the top and scrunches it to about 200px high. Maybe I'm using it wrong...?

Comment: I found gtile unintuitive at first, but after working with it a bit, I really like it. My breakthrough moment was realizing that after pressing SUPER+G, you are presented with a grid (which you can customize), and you select the two corners of the grid to put the window into. For example, if you have a 4x4 grid and you want the window to take up half the screen, click on the regions 0,0 and 1,3. I customized mine so I can quickly put windows where I need them without extra zones.

Comment: The mentioned customization of the grid can be done as follows: System Settings -> Extensions -> Manage -> gTitle -> click on the settings wheels on the right -> Select "Behavior" -> Disable "Use monitor aspect ractio". Then Select "Layout". Now you can configure the different layouts.

Comment: One more usage hint: Super+G. Then click on the first corner and then click on the second corner. -- I did not know that at the start and had WTFs when using it the first time.