# In Cinnamon, when pressing super+right, how to move to next display

Tags: cinnamon

My muscle memory is used to press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>cursor right</kbd> until the Window is in the right position. I know that <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>cursor right</kbd> can be used to instantly move to the next screen. However, then I need to use <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>cursor right</kbd> to adjust it to the right "tile".

Is it possible to configure Cinnamon not to stop window moving if a corner of the screen is hit, but continue moving to the next screen?

---

Related question: [How to customize window tiling zones/grid?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/338415/18033) 
Related tool: [Window Shuffler](https://frontpagelinux.com/tutorials/window-shuffler-tiling-window-management-from-ubuntu-budgie/), but only available on Ubuntu Budgie.